# Is It Possible to control User Access On An OAuth Client Application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

Our OAuth client application is built with Spring (through JHipster). The OAuth provider only serves the authentication functionality, but not the authorization functionality. Ideally, we should only allow a small group of people to access our OAuth client application, but not all those users who can sign in to the OAuth provider.

A solution I can think of at this moment is to create a custom user role to control the access in the OAuth client application. That, however, only can be done after the user's first sign-in when the user account data is created in the application.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would apply user access control *before* creating user account data is created in the application. You could do so by providing an application specific `scope` or `claim` in the token that is generated for your application (aka. Client). Upon receiving the token, the application would check for the required attribute in the token before allowing access.